# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..13: 14

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to set custom value at 0'th index of _menuItems.

This is what i have done so far:

```
  int _value;
  List<custom.DropdownMenuItem<int>> _menuItems;

  initDropdown() {
    dynamic data = Provider.of<RestApiData>(context, listen: false).data;
    List dataList = data[1]["offers"];

    _menuItems = List<custom.DropdownMenuItem<int>>(dataList.length+1);
    _menuItems[0] = custom.DropdownMenuItem(
      value: -1,
      child: Text(
        'allOffers'.tr().toString(),
        style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 14.0),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border:
              Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black54, width: 0.5))),
    );

    for (int i = 1; i <= _menuItems.length; i++) {
      _menuItems[i] = custom.DropdownMenuItem(
        value: int.parse(dataList[i]["Offer"]["id"]),
        child: Text(
          "${dataList[i]["Offer"]["name"]}",
          style:
              GoogleFonts.ubuntu(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 14.0),
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border:
                Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black54, width: 0.5))),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initDropdown();
  }
```

I have tried this way but getting RangeError.
Any help will be appreciate.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has solved.
I forgot to subtract 1 from mentioned lines.

```
int _value;
  List<custom.DropdownMenuItem<int>> _menuItems;

  initDropdown() {
    dynamic data = Provider.of<RestApiData>(context, listen: false).data;
    List dataList = data[1]["offers"];

    _menuItems = List<custom.DropdownMenuItem<int>>(dataList.length + 1);

    _menuItems[0] = custom.DropdownMenuItem(
      value: -1,
      child: Text(
        'allOffers'.tr().toString(),
        style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 14.0),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border:
              Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black54, width: 0.5))),
    );

    for (int i = 1; i < _menuItems.length; i++) {
      _menuItems[i] = custom.DropdownMenuItem(
        value: int.parse(dataList[i - 1]["Offer"]["id"]), //**here**
        child: Text(
          "${dataList[i - 1]["Offer"]["name"]}", //**here**
          style:
              GoogleFonts.ubuntu(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 14.0),
        ),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border:
                Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black54, width: 0.5))),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`RangeError` means you are trying to get an element at index which doesn't exist. Y Your list has 14 elements and it is indexed starting from 0 to 13 and you are trying to get element at index 14 which is impossible

Remove equality from the condition of loop, and it will work

```
              
for (int i = 1; i < _menuItems.length; i++){
           .....................
}
```

If you are confused, print value of `i` in loop

Comment: thanks for answer but i want to put a custom value at _menuItems[0] index. the solution that you have suggested doesn't works .

Comment: you mean, you will put some value at index 0, and provide the others with for loop?

Comment: yes right. the other indexes should provided by json data coming from api.

Comment: i have tried this way before but the custom value replaces dataList's first element

Comment: wasnt it what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: No I want to list all of data that comes from api with custom value at 0'th index without replacing api data